Gaining access to `~/Library/Mobile Documents` in a launch agent
I use restic for computer backups on macOS Sonoma. I have a shell script that invokes the restic binary with custom arguments. To make a backup, I run the shell script manually in the terminal, something like: ./backup-home-mac.sh. This script has a list of directories that I want to back up, which includes ~/Library/Mobile Documents, my iCloud root directory. restic has been able to scan the directory and read all files there.
Now I am trying to automate the backup as a Launch Agent. Here's an example of someone else doing this.
My plist looks like this:
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/zsh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/Users/me/backup/backup-home-mac.sh</string>
  </array>

Originally restic couldn't read anything in my home directory, until I added /bin/zsh to the list of programs with "Full Disk Access." Now, launched as an agent, restic starts and is able to read all my directories except for one: ~/Library/Mobile Documents. Here are its logs:
start scan on [...my directories...]
start backup on [...my directories...]
scan: open /Users/me/Library/Mobile Documents: operation not permitted

When I run this script manually, restic continues to be able to read this directory. So, it must be something specific to running as a Launch Agent. As this software already has "Full Disk Access", I don't know what more I can do.
One solution I tried is changing the plist to call restic directly instead of my shell script, and granting restic (instead of zsh) "Full Disk Access". But that didn't affect the behavior.
Can anyone advise how I can grant zsh and/or restic access to my iCloud files when running as a Launch Agent?

Just a guess: It might be launchd setting some runtime restrictions, or changing environment parameters like uid when launching your launch agents. Can you check the effective execution environment of the launchagent (like set it to run "id(1)")
